# How to build a fixed footer in NativeScript-Vue?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I would like to have a fixed footer in a page, but I tried with

```
<StackLayout>
```

and a

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
```

and in the container parent

```
position: relative
```

but nothing happened.

I tried with

```
<AbsoluteLayout bottom="0">
```

and nothing happened again.

Someone knows how to do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

The `<AbsoluteLayout>` places elements absolutely **inside it**. With NativeScript, we have to use Layout Containers to place elements inside them.

The best layouts to achieve what you want zare:

1) `<DockLayout>`, e.g.

```
<DockLayout>
  <Label dock="bottom" height="60" backgroundColor="yellow" text="footer"/>
  <Label text="rest of the content"/>
</DockLayout>
```

2) `<GridLayout>`, e.g.

```
<GridLayout columns="*, 60">
  <Label col="0" text="rest of the content"/>
  <Label col="1" text="footer"/>
</GridLayout>
```

Please study the [layout containers documentation](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/layouts/layout-containers).

Comment: Ok, thank you! The other problem is that I would like to insert, inside the footer a text with three anchor links, how I can do this? 
For example, I have:

`<DockLayout>
 <Label dock="bottom" class="footer" text="footer" />
</DockLayout>`

But I would like to add a text that contains, inside, an anchor link: how could I do this?

Comment: You really need to dig deeper into the docs, @P1_10. Or see some demo apps like this one: https://github.com/tralves/groceries-ns-vue. In native apps we avoid "anchor links", and instead we use `<Button>`s. In your case, I would nest a `<GridLayout>`. Something like: 
`<DockLayout> <GridLayout dock="bottom" class="footer" columns="*,*,*" > <Button text="button 1" col="0"/>   <Button text="button 2" col="1"/>  <Button text="button 3" col="2"/>   </GridLayout> </DockLayout>`